# How can I use scrapy on booking.com without being blocked?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, web-mining

I am trying to scrape hotel reviews from booking.com with the python plugin scrapy.

My problem is, that the desired data (e.g. negative feedbacks) can't be found by scrapy. I think, it's because of the javascript code embedded in the site.

Therefore, I tried to change my user-agent in the settings.py file but nothing changed. Then I tried to emulate a browser request but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Here is the link to the hotel I want to scrape the reviews of: https://www.booking.com/hotel/de/best-western-plus-marina-star-lindau.de.html

This is my Spider:

```
import scrapy


class FeedbacktestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feedbacktest'
    allowed_domains = ['www.booking.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/hotel/de/best-western-plus-marina-star-lindau.de.html']

def start_requests(self):
    urls=['https://www.booking.com/hotel/de/best-western-plus-marina-star-lindau.de.html']
   
    headers = {
'Host': 'www.booking.com',
'Device-Memory': '8',
'DPR': '1',
'Viewport-Width': '1920',
'RTT': '50',
'Downlink': '10',
'ECT': '4g',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'DNT': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.45',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
'Referer':'https://www.booking.com/',
'Accept-Encoding':' gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language':'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
'Cookie':'__utma=12798129.959027148.1615055069.1615055069.1615055069.1; __utmc=12798129; __utmz=12798129.1615055069.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utmt=1; __utmb=12798129.1.10.1615055069'
}
           
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse, headers=headers)

def parse(self, response):
    pos = response.xpath("//div[@class='althotelsDiv2 use_sprites_no_back featured_reviewer']/p/span/text()").extract()
    
    yield{
        'pos': pos
        }
```

For the User-Agent in the settings.py I tried my own User-Agent and the Google-Agent.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem:

I viewed the site I want to scrape with my network tool and looked for the request where the desired data is requested.

Then I scraped for this link instead of the originial link and in my scrapy settings.py I set the ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False, so that I don't get blocked by the site.

Comment: There is also a reason that robots.txt exists. The site doesn't want to be scraped. As long as you know that, it's fine, but it's important to know.

Comment: You can also do Rotating Proxies strategies.